# jQuery selector all ids that are integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select all ids which are the integers.

for example

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
```

somdething `[id^="integer"]`?

I know how to select ids that has similar name starting:

```
[id^="similar_"]
```

Comment: Ids starting by number arent valid.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon in HTML5 it's valid. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id in HTML  you can have it .

Comment: you can add prefix to the ids and use your `[id^="similar_"]` solution.

Comment: IDs starting with numbers are merely a bad idea -- IDs and classes should be semantically descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2rjJV/)

```
$('[id]').filter(function () {
    return !isNaN((this.id)[0]) && this.id.indexOf('.') === -1;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

[Has Attribute Selector [name]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Please don't wrap your hyperlinks within `<kbd>` elements for decoration purposes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `filter()`. The equivalent of `[id^=integer]` would be :

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return this.id.match(/^\d/);
})
```

Only integer would be :

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return this.id.match(/^\d+$/);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div').filter(function(){ return this.id.match(/^\d+$/) })
```

Comment: That would match `id="test1"`

Answer (score 3):

No need to use regex here...

```
$('div').filter(function(){ 
    return this.id && !isNaN(this.id) && this.id % 1===0;
});

isNaN(123)     // false
isNaN('123')   // false
isNaN('foo')   // true
isNaN('10px')  // true
```

Comment: floats would return false

Comment: Correction: `$('div').filter(function(){ return !isNaN(+this.id); })`. Your code would return IDs which are blank as well.

Comment: @kayen it would also still return floats

Comment: @Johan Looking at the edits, wouldn't it be much simpler to use RegExp now? #justSaying

Comment: @Johan there is *no need* but can you tell me the advantage of using this?. It is less readable and slower!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon No advantage - just an alternative.